# Saving openpyxl file via text and filestream

Tags: python, excel, filestream, openpyxl

I'm building OpenPyXL into an application that expects a string containing the content of the excel file, for it to write via file stream.

From my investigation into the OpenPyXL source code, it doesn't look like it supports this kind of output. Does anyone have any experience with modifying openpyxl to support this?

Or any general advice/workarounds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 53):

In openpyxl 2.6 calling the `save_virtual_workbook` method issues the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated function save_virtual_workbook (Use a NamedTemporaryFile).
```

At some point `save_virtual_workbook` will be removed from openpyxl.

In Python 3 typical usage to save an openpyxl workbook to a filestream becomes:

```
from io import BytesIO
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
with NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    wb.save(tmp.name)
    output = BytesIO(tmp.read())
```

After looking at the implementation of the WorkBook `save` method, the 'filename' is sent straight to ZipFile which accepts a path or file-like object so there is no need for a NamedTemporaryFile and simply use in-memory BytesIO:

```
from io import BytesIO
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
virtual_workbook = BytesIO()
wb.save(virtual_workbook)

# now use virtual_workbook to send to a stream; email attachment, etc
```

Comment: Could you please care to answer as to how we are supposed to send virtual_workbook to send to a stream or an email or via an API response.

Comment: Saving directly to a `BytesIO` does not work here for some reason. But anyway, it is more of a hack based on private code so I wouldn't recommend doing that on production code as there is no guarantee that private code will not change. The suggested code with `NamedTemporaryFile` works fine though, and is also suggested by the deprecation message for `save_virtual_workbook`!

Comment: BytesIO works fine, but remember to move to the beginning of the file before reading it content:
virtual_workbook.seek(0)
data = virtual_workbook.read()

Comment: @Andrei Good catch with the need to call to seek. calling `.seek(0)` before the read works!

Answer (score 50):

jcollado's answer is actually valid, but there is also a function (sadly not documented yet) called "save_virtual_workbook" in openpyxl.writer.excel that will take your workbook and return the workbook as a string:

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook

wb = Workbook()
print save_virtual_workbook(wb)
```

What you're looking for is the string returned by save_virtual_workbook()

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to save via filestream. You can also save it like:

`io.BytesIO(save_virtual_workbook(wb))`

Comment: We should not use this function anymore. `Deprecated: Use a NamedTemporaryFile`. See [the documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#saving-as-a-stream)

Answer (score 19):

What about using a `StringIO` object to save the contents of the file:

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from StringIO import StringIO

output = StringIO()
wb = Workbook()
wb.save(output)
print output.getvalue()
```

The string you're looking for is what is being printed in the last line of this example.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work.. instead of a IO-Byte-object thing, wb.save() is just expecting a filename (a str-object)

Comment: Confirming that this does not work. Whatever you provide to the save method of the wb is trying to be used as the filename.

Comment: My openpyxl 2.3.3. works with this, but requires `io.BytesIO`

Comment: Just to support this - checking the [openpxyl code on this](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/93604327bce7aac5e8270674579af76d390e09c0/openpyxl/writer/excel.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#excel.py-221), it just passes the `filename` to Python's [ZipFile library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) which accepts _either_ a filename _or_ a file-like object (such as `BytesIO`).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find out since what version this has been the case.

Answer (score 10):

A compatible implementation with `save_virtual_workbook` deprecated since version 2.6:

```py
from io import BytesIO
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


def save_virtual_workbook(workbook):
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as tf:
        workbook.save(tf.name)
        in_memory = BytesIO(tf.read())
        return in_memory.getvalue()
```

Comment: I have tried that method but I'm getting `Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable`. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62519571/output-json-file-as-excel-formated-filestream

Comment: @JackTheKnife Are you working with Django Rest framework? It would be helpful if you can provide your minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from io import BytesIO

rows = [[1,2], [3,4]]

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

for row in rows:
    sheet.append(row)

io = BytesIO
book.save(io)

content = io.getValue()

return Response(
    content,
    mimetype=magic.from_buffer(content, mime=True),
    headers={
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename=' + 'test.xlsx'}
)
```

Comment: I needed the openpyxl  to use the font colors

Comment: there's a typo, should be `content = io.getvalue()`

Comment: This solution not working in the latest version of python and openpyxl. `TypeError: descriptor 'tell' of '_io.BytesIO' object needs an argument`

Comment: @MrAlihoseiny you are getting this error because `io` is assigned to the function of `BytesIO`. To get the value of `BytesIO` call it like this `io = BytesIO()`